# Java Calendar timezone converting to GMT problem

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

I have one Calendar object which is as per the user's time zone which may be PST etc, now i want to convert the same to GMT and retain the time i.e. is the calendar initially was set @ 00:00:00 at PST it should be converted to 08:00:00 after the conversion taking into consideration the time/date difference . Can someone provide me some help on this.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Thanks,

Vaibhav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a new Calendar in GMT, set the time in that calendar to the same as the original calendar, and you're done:

```
gmtCalendar.setTime(userCalendar.getTime());
```

That should be fine, as the `getTime()` call returns the *instant* in time (i.e. a `java.util.Date` with no associated time zone).

As ever though, if you're doing any significant amount of date/time work in Java you should strongly consider using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
( ( GregorianCalendar ) myCal )  // Cast from a general `Calendar`  to  specific subclass `GregorianCalendar`. 
    .toZonedDateTime()           // Convert from troublesome legacy class to modern java.time class, `ZonedDateTime`.
    .toInstant()                 // Extract a UTC-specific value, an `Instant` object.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

Convert your legacy `Calendar` object (if `GregorianCalendar`) to a `ZonedDateTime`. Call new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCal ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Now extract an `Instant`, a value always in UTC. You can think of it this way conteptually: ZonedDateTime = ( Instant + ZoneId )

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

For more flexibility such as generating strings in various formats, convert to an `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).